# Why did the french government disempower the legislative (which had an oppositional opinion to a proposed act) to force an unpopular act?

Tags: democracy, france

To cite [this article from rubikon.news](https://www.rubikon.news/artikel/der-prasidentschaftswahlkampf-in-frankreich-nuit-debout-und-ein-neues-68):

> Denn was französische Regierungen zum wiederholten Mal durchzusetzen
>   versuchen (zuletzt mit einer ‚Rentenreform’ unter Nicolas Sarcosy),
>   ist in Deutschland sang- und klanglos über die Bühne gegangen: Die
>   Agenda 2010 unter der damaligen rot-grünen Regierung: Ein großes
>   Festival des Kapitals – eine einzige Niederlage der Gewerkschaften und
>   der (außerparlamentarischen) Linken.
>
> [...] In Deutschland fand die ‚Agenda 2010’ eine
>   ausreichende, satte parlamentarische Mehrheit. **In Frankreich reicht es
>   nicht einmal dazu.** Selbst Mitglieder der Regierungspartei drohten mit
>   einem ‚Nein’. **Daraufhin entschied sich die Regierung Hollandes dazu,
>   das Parlament einfach zu entmachten, indem sie das Gesetz per Dekret
>   in Kraft setzte.**

That translates roughly to:

> Because what the french government yet again tried to force (lately with a "pension reform" under Nicolas Sarcozy), was in Germany decided without resistence. The "Agenda 2010" under the red-green government: a festival of the capital - a defeat of the labor unions and the left party.
>
> In Germany, the "Agenda 2010" found a parliamentary majority. **In France, the proposal of the pension reform hadn't faound a parliamentary majority.** Even members of the governing party threatened with a "No". **Therefore, the government of Hollande decided to disempower the parliament to force this act.**
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

Disempowering the legislative (the parliament) to be able to ignore an oppositional opinion is not democratic, in my opinion.
Of course, an easy answer would be that the Holland' government is just corrupt and not democratic - so they abused their power to decrease the social state and democracy.

But i don't believe in easy answers. I **hope** that this easy answer does not apply here. So what was the reason for the french government to

- disempower the legislative, an essential component of the french democracy?
- force an act which the legislative didn't want?

I ask for the justification/motivation from the french government.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking: the German article seems to speak about the "loi Travail" (the Work Act) or "loi El Khomri" (El Khomri Act, from the name of the Minister that supported it) and its popular opposition. The act was passed using the Article 49 of the Constitution of the French Republic, that establishes the relation between the government and the Parliament. Although some politicians consider about abrogating it, it is perfectly legal and democratic (in the sense of "conform with the democratically accepted constitution). This has NOTHING to do with the current emergency state.

Answer (score 8):

This question is based on a complete misunderstanding of what happened.

The article you're quoting is about the [El Khomri law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Khomri_law), often also called the "Loi travail" ("Work law"). Facing opposition in the parliament, the government decided to [commit its responsibility to the bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_49_of_the_French_Constitution#Commitment_of_responsibility_on_a_bill_.2849.3.29) using Article 49-3 of the Constitution. This means that the law passes without a vote of the parliament, unless the representatives vote a motion of censure against the government, in which case the law doesn't pass *and* the government must resign.

This procedure is completely and utterly unrelated to the [state of emergency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_of_emergency_in_France)(which had been asserted in a [previous version of this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/revisions/18425/3)) that has been in effect since November 2015. The state of emergency is about extended powers for the police (searching homes, detaining people before their trial, forbidding some demonstrations). The state of emergency normally lasts 12 days at most, and the parliament has to pass a law to extend it every time.

In both cases, if the parliament was really opposed to the government passing the law or extending the state of emergency, they could. They didn't. No one ignored democratic rules. To talk about dictatorship is an insult to all the people victims of actual dictatorship.